# Add items to an array with no set size within a "while (reader.Read())"

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I have this method:

```
    int[] lowStockArray;
    private void checkForLowStockTimer()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,Stock,LowStock FROM Beans WHERE id = @ID", conn))
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", coffeeID);
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString()) <= Int32.Parse(reader["LowStock"].ToString()))
                    {
                        lowStockArray = Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString());
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and at:

```
lowStockArray = Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString());
```

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'"

I'm use to loop with loop numbers and arrays with set sizes such as:

```
int[] foo= new int[400];
for (int bar= 0; runs < 400; bar++)
{
    foo[bar] = value;
}
```

With the while (reader.Read() atleast however I don't know how to pull a loop number for the [] out of it if thats what I need.

I thought I could just add on to the array.

Comment: declare List<int> and then use                        lowStockArray.add(Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString()));
to add the item

Comment: As an aside, it would be a lot cleaner to set values for `stock` and `lowStock` just once, declaring them after the `while` and using them instead of calling the reader several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic List to store your data and finally get an array from it.

```
var myList = new List<int>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString()) <=   Int32.Parse(reader["LowStock"].ToString()))
    {
        myList.Add(Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString()));
    }                        
}
var array = myList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that you are trying to give your array the value of an int, instead of setting an element of your array.

This is true since

```
Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString())
```

returns an int, but lowStockArray  is an array.

You could declare an int outside of the loop

```
int i = 0;
```

and then increment it's value every time you add something to your array.

```
lowStockArray[i] = Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString());
i++;
```

Comment: Hi does not know the size of `lowStockArray`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to instantiate your array and keep track of the array index and increment it each pass in the loop.

Or to simplify things, change

```
int[] lowStockArray;
```

to

```
List<int> lowStockArray = new List<int>()
```

and change

```
lowStockArray = Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString());
```

to

```
lowStockArray.Add(Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString()));
```

Then later on, you can call `lowStockArray.ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 int[] lowStockArray;
```

to

```
 List<int> lowStockList = new List<int>();
```

and

```
lowStockArray = Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString());
```

to

```
lowStockList.Add(Int32.Parse(reader["Stock"].ToString()));
```

To get an array: `lowStockList.ToArray()`